# Cron Job Command To Delete 0 Byte Files

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cronjob

I need to have a Cron Job, that when it runs automatically deletes all of the files inside of a folder that are exactly 0 bytes.

The script I am using allows users to enter their username so it downloads their file. However, I want the script to be basic so there is nothing that checks to see if the file exists. If it doesn't exists, it uploads nothing, but it still uploads a blank file that contains nothing, and is exactly 0 bytes.

I could not find anything on this, but I could have been searching for the wrong things as Im not exactly sure what this would be called.

Answer (score 1):

To find all 0 byte files in *directory*, you can use this command:

```
find directory -maxdepth 1 -size 0
```

Remove the `-maxdepth 1` switch if you want to search in sub-directories as well.

To delete those files, just add a `-delete` switch at the end:

```
find directory -maxdepth 1 -size 0 -delete
```

Comment: Testing it now, Ill let you know results.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working for me, all I have to do is replace directory with the exact location right? I do know that the directory is correct, what else could be going wrong?

Comment: Did you try directly from the command line or as a cron job? For a crontab entry, you might have to specify the full path of find. To debug a cron job, add `2>> pathtologfile` and check the log file for error messages.

Comment: (1) Some versions of `find` support a `-empty` predicate (a.k.a. “primary”) that means `-size 0`.  (2) Not all versions of `find` support `-delete`.  `-exec rm` is more portable.

Comment: When will this cron job run?  If it will run in the middle of the night, when users are absolutely ***guaranteed*** not to be active, ignore this next part.  But if it will run at a time when users might be active, I suggest adding `-mtime +1`, so the command will handle only files that are at least a day old.  This precaution is to protect against the race condition where a user starts to upload a file, and then the cron job runs and deletes it, and then user’s script finishes uploading the file –– but, too late; it’s already been deleted.

Comment: @Scott: To use `-empty`, you have to specify `-type f` as well or find will also list/delete empty directories.